# Laravel, data update Error. There is no error reminder, but the data does not insert into database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I encounter a problem that the data cannot be stored in the database. when I use the save function to update a column, there is no error reminder and does not insert as well. I have no idea. Help me, Bro.

I have a supervisor table that includes the id, user_id, name, email, expertise, and initial letter columns. the primary key is user_id.

this is my route for an edit view

```
Route::get('supervisor/profile/{id}/edit','UserController@supProfileEdit');
```

this is the view to post the new data.

```
Route::post('supervisor/profile/{id}','UserController@supProfileUpdate');
```

a blade is a form :

```
 <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header bg-primary text-white">Profile</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            @foreach($supervisor as $data)
                <form id="supProfileForm" type="POST" action="{{url('supervisor/profile',$data->user_id)}}"
                      enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <div>
                        <label for="name"> Name : </label>
                        <input  id="name" disabled value="{{$data->name}}">

                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label for="email">Email : </label>
                        <input id="email"  disabled value="{{$data->email}}">
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label class="inline" for="expertise">Expertise : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="expertise" name="expertise" value="{{$data->expertise}}">
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

Then, this is my function in Controller: I just wanna update the expertise.

```
public function supProfileUpdate(Supervisor $supervisor)
    {

        $this->validate(request(),[
            'expertise'=>'required',
        ]);
        $supervisor->expertise = request('expertise');
        $supervisor->save();
        return redirect()->back();

    }
```

Comment: what is `$supervisor` in the view and why are you iterating it?

Comment: the supervisor is a list of supervisors in the database

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem caused by

```
Route::post('supervisor/profile/{id}','UserController@supProfileUpdate');
```

where the Supervisor model primary key is id while you trying to get it using the user_id key.

So I will suggest that you either implement getRouteKeyName in Supervisor model as follows

```
 /**
 * Get the route key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'user_id';
}
```

or by using the id when sending it to the form

```
<form id="supProfileForm" type="POST" action="{{url('supervisor/profile',$data->id)}}"
```

Comment: Thank u, bro. but It does not work for my code. I have no idea about it. sad

Comment: could you check what is the value of $supervisor in supProfileUpdate function before validating the data